# Возврат значения из интерфейса

Tags: java, android

Всех приветствую. Появилась такая проблема:

Пытаюсь вернуть строку из метода интерфейса. Появляется такая ошибка:

> Variable 'resp' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be
>   declared final

Код:

```
public String Detect(String text){
        String url = "some_link"+text;
        String resp = "";
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    resp = String.valueOf(response.getString("some_variable"));
                   // Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(response.getString("some_variable")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
            }
        });

        return resp;
    }
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Это не интерфейс, а анонимный класс, реализующий интерфейс. Это разные вещи )
2. Записать в локальную переменную у вас реально так не получится, что и написал компилятор. Причина очень простая - методы анонимного класса могут вызваться когда угодно, то есть асинхронно и это может случится намного позже, за пределами этой функции. Собственно никакой переменной и не будет в тот момент. В принципе это можно обойти - AtomicReference и .set().

Судя по тому что я вижу здесь, у вас AsyncHttpClient - судя по названию код метода действительно будет вызван асинхронно (то есть грубо говоря неизвестно когда). То есть функция `Detect` будет выполнена мгновенно, но response к вам придет намного позже, будет получен вообще в отдельном, другом потоке и когда это случится вызовется метод интерфейса `onSuccess`. А значит `return resp;` - не имеет никакого смысла. И даже использование AtomicReference приведет к null если вы попытаетесь считать значение сразу за пределами функции. Эту проблему решают двумя способами:

1. Синхронизация. Просто дожидаемся завершения запроса, как-то например вот так:

   ```
   AtomicReference<String> result = Detect("...");
   while(result.get() == null) {}
   ```

Подойдет в принципе, если будете делать это в отдельном потоке. Но такой код - ужас, лучше поискать синхронный клиент, который делает это все за вас.

2. В данном случае ваш интерфейс это колбек, который вызовется когда данные будут получены. И поэтому желательно перейти к асинхронному программированию. В данном случае вы переходите от последовательного кода:

   ```
   Object result = firstAction();
   secondAction(result);
   ```

К асинхронному:

```
firstAction(new Resulthandler() {
    void actionFinished(Object result) {
        secondAction(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Использование локальной переменной во внутреннем анонимном классе (у вас это - JsonHttpResponseHandler) требует "финализировать" ее (о чем вам, собственно, и написали).

Самый простой вариант из того кода, что есть - возвращать не переменную, а сразу значение. В т.ч. из блока `try`.